I've removed an email from play console's "Users and permissions" secton, but Google Play Support still sending emails to that email
I have removed an email from play console's "Users and permissions" secton, but Google Play Support still sending emails to that email regarding my apps. How to completely stop this. I'm searching a solution from 2 months, got nothing.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic
